# How to restrict login with old password in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When I change AD password using ldap I can login using both old and new passwords for few minutes.

Can I disallow logins with old password or is there any way I can reduce validity of changed password to few seconds instead of minutes.

Comment: This is a replication issue, there is no facility to log into AD with old passwords.

Comment: I am using ldap authentication with java http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Authenticate_Users_with_Active_Directory 
And when I change AD password, it continues to authenticate with old password.

Comment: you can change the OldPasswordAllowedPeriod, You can view http://serverfault.com/questions/461139/ntlm-auth-can-login-in-ad-with-both-old-and-new-passwords.